# Perl SimpleXML : How to access a value with no key

Tags: perl, hash, simplexml

I've got an XML file, When I do a `print Dumper` on my now `$data->{Foo}`, I get the following output.

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'Bar' => { 
                       ...etc...
                     }
          },
          {
            'Bar' => {
                       ...etc2...
                     }
          }
         ];
```

How do I print what's under the second Bar? I tried:

```
$data->{Foo}{1}->{Bar}
```

But that's incorrect syntax.

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Also tried a few different variations: 
$data->{foo}->{bar}[1]
$data->{foo}->{1}->{bar}

Comment: `{bar}` is not the same thing as `{Bar}`. Please say what you mean and mean what you say.

Comment: sorry, excuse the case sensitivity mistake. it's corrected now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to get in trouble if you leave out the first '->'.

If you say `$foo->[0]` Perl thinks that `foo` is a scalar that's a reference to an array, and then returns the first element of that referenced array.

If you say `$foo[0]` Perl thinks that `foo` is an array, and returns it's first element.

You also need to be careful about `[]` vs. `{}`.  `[]` are for array lookups, `{}` are for hash lookups. Perl can convince an array that it's a hash if it really wants to, with surprising results sometimes.

So, given all that, you need to say something like this:

`$data->{Foo}[1]{Bar};`

or more pedantically:

`$data->{Foo}->[1]->{Bar};`

Given the comments below, the first form is preferred for what I think are pretty obvious reasons.  See 'Using References' in `perldoc perlref` for more details.

Comment: Looking at this again, you may be able to leave out all '->'s after the first one, resulting in `$data->{Foo}[1]{Bar};`

Comment: You can (and I dare say *should*) leave out all `->` after the first. `$data->{Foo}[1]{Bar}` is the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, I think should is correct.  I've just been using a few other languages lately, and wasn't 100% until I tested it.  Post first, answer questions later.  :)